# How to initiate MS SQL trusted connection for PHP

Tags: php, sql-server, trustedconnection

I have been trying to initiate database trusted connection to MS SQL using PHP but failed. My PHP development machine is not part of the domain and the MS SQL server is in a domain. Unfortunately I cannot join my development machine to the domain. My DBA is reluctant to change the authentication mode of the SQL server.

Is there anyway for me to connect to the MS SQL server with trusted connection using PHP with just a domain logon credential?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In Asp.net we can use  `Integrated Security=True";`or `Trusted_Connection=Yes;`in your connection string 
or `Trusted Connection=SSPI" in connection string`

in php 
go to the `php.ini` and verify the `mssql.secure_connection` parameter :

```
[MSSQL]

mssql.secure_connection = On
```

Comment: Thanks Arun but my script is a PHP script. How do I add that?

Comment: @cheetooh sorry i mentioned only asp.net case, chek my updated ans it will deals php windows authentication too

Comment: Thanks for your reply again! Sorry forgot to mention I am running PHP on IIS 7.5. I found the setting in php.ini file and I have changed it. Then, I changed the Anonymous Authentication to a valid domain user login credential. But I am getting the error >Login failed for user ''. The user is not associated with a trusted SQL Server connection

Comment: This problem occurs if the user tries to log in with credentials that cannot be validated.

because of more than one resons the same error may occur. anyway try the following.

open your sql server management studio 
then open Object explorer
then ight click on Server Node and select Properties
then go to Security Tab and go to Server Authentical Area. 
then Select SQL Server and Windows Authentication Mode.
and press ok 
then try to connect